# Javafx: Padding line

Tags: java, javafx, padding

I want to use a padding with the class `javafx.scene.shape.Line` in a `javafx.scene.layout.VBox`.
FXML (is included in a other one):

```
<Tab xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller=...>
    <VBox>
        <Pane>...</Pane>
        <Line fx:id="line"/>
        ...
    </VBox>
</Tab>
```

I tryed it with CSS and padding tags in FXML. I also tryed java code (in the controller class):

```
@FXML MyLine spacerLine;
...
line.setStartX(5);
line.setEndX(scene.getWidth() - 5);
```

However nothing helped. Thanks for help and reading.

Comment: I'm not sure "padding" is what you really mean here. [`padding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#paddingProperty) is defined for a `Region` (a `Line` is not a `Region`), and it is the amount of space "around the region's content". A line has no content (no child nodes, etc). So what are you actually expecting to see if you set the padding to something?

Comment: I need something like this: `[space to border]________[space to border]`. So the line dosen't touch the border. I have edited my question, there was a mistake.

Comment: So you are looking for something like an HTML [horizontal rule](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that what you are looking for is something like a horizontal rule, I would recommend using a `Region` for this, and styling it using CSS.

The problem with using a `Line` is that you will either make the line `managed` (which is the default), or not managed. If it is managed, the layout pane in which it is contained will position it according to the layout rules, so you won't be able to specify a `startX`, for example. If it is not managed, you need to compute both its `x` and `y` coordinates; so for example in a `VBox` you would need to position it by hand relative to the other child nodes of the `VBox`. In either case, you would also need to compute the `endX` based on the width of the container, which could change at any time (e.g. if the user resizes the window).

Using a region, you can just do

```xml
<Region styleClass="hr" />
```

and then apply appropriate styles in an external CSS file, for example:

```css
.hr {
        -fx-background-color: slategray ;
        -fx-background-insets: 2 5 2 5 ;

        -fx-padding: 3 0 2 0  ;
}
```

This works by using the background color (`slategrey`, but you can of course choose anything you like) to paint the rule, but uses insets to leave 5 pixels unfilled on the left and right, and 2 pixels unfilled on the top and bottom. The padding ensures that the region has three pixels at the top (2 unfilled, 1 filled) and 2 pixels at the bottom (unfilled). So this ends up with a filled region one pixel high (looking like a horizontal line), stretching the full width less 5 pixels at each end. You can experiment with different insets and padding to get different effects; e.g. `-fx-background-insets: 0 5 0 5;` and padding of `1 0 0 0` will remove the space around the top and bottom, if you want. Using insets of 5 on all sides but a padding of `9 0 5 0` will give a 4px wide line, etc. You can use gradients for the fill, too...

Here's a complete FXML file (`HRWithRegion.fxml`) to test this out:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox spacing="5">
        <Label text="Some content"/>
        <TextField />
        <Label text="Some more content"/>
    </VBox>
    <Region styleClass="hr" />
    <VBox>
        <Label text="Content below rule" />
    </VBox>
</VBox>
```

And a JavaFX application class: just place the FXML file above in the same folder as the source code here, and the CSS file as `hr.css`, again in the same folder.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HRTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HRWithRegion.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("hr.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here's the result (after resizing the window):

[image]